# Excel use 2 criteria to find value

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup, sumproduct

I want to find the price of a product based on the client name and the product.

One table has the brand column, the product column and the empty price. The second table has the brand column, the product, and the price.

I am trying to use sumproduct but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Thankx

Comment: Looks like you want to use a `Match()` for finding an entry in a table and then use a `VLookup()` to find that result in the second table. Can you edit your question, show what your tables look like and what you're trying to find?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT should work. Please feel free to share your formula so we can help to check. If you don’t mind to get a table (multiple lines) as a result you could also use the FILTER with multiple criteria instead. With VLOOKUP you would need to create a helper column with the combined value of the 2 columns to match with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I have understood the question correctly, but here goes:

[image]

```
=SUMIFS($G$3:$G$12,$E$3:$E$12,$A3,$F$3:$F$12,$B3)
```

This returns to table 1, the price in table 2 which matches the brand and product in table 2.

This does assume that there is only one entry for a particular Brand/Product combination (as it would sum them together if there is more than one. And it returns zero if no match is found.

If I have not understood, please let me know and I will edit my answer.

**EDIT - Using `SUMPRODUCT`**

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT` but it is not needed in this case as `SUMIFS` is simpler and relies on the same assumptions:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$3:$E$12=$A3),--($F$3:$F$12=$B3),$G$3:$G$12)
```

**A Note on `VLOOKUP`**

I see a couple of people in the comments suggesting `VLOOKUP`.

I would go so far as to say that `VLOOKUP` should **NEVER** be used... **EVER**. `INDEX`/`MATCH` can do everything `VLOOKUP` can do and more. It is more efficient, more versatile and easier to use as there is no need to count columns. And because of that it is more stable because inserting columns does not cause it to break.